# Trying to lerp between two point but get NullReferenceException [ unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to lerp between two points in my script but i get NullReferenceException
here is the code:

```
    Transform  endPos;
    float speed;
 void Start()
    {
       endPos.position = new Vector3(0, -1, 1);

    }
 void  Update()
    {
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, endPos.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Interesting thing is that when i set the transform to public and set it in editor it works.
I even tried to use it through creating a gameObject and set the postion through there but no luck.
so how can i do it through script and not editor?
Thanks.

Comment: In this code you're not initializing `endPos`. Are you sure the issue comes from transform?

Comment: The `NullReferenceException` does happen when you try to access/reference non-initialized reference type objects properties or methods. In your `Start` method, before accesing the position property, you should instantiate and set its properties in a similar way you do in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because your `endPos` transform is null when you try to set its position. Use `Vector3` instead of transform. Edit your code like this

```
    Vector3 endPos;
    float speed;

    void Start()
    {
       endPos = new Vector3(0, -1, 1);    
    }

    void Update()
    {
       transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, endPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```